# VBA - IF a cell in column A = Value, then copy values in column B starting in D4 of the newworksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro to create a separate sheet for each unique value in column A. I have succesfully done that but I am struggling in the next part of my coding.

I wanted to copy to the new worksheet starting from D4, worksheet name the same with unique value in column A, the values from columnn C if the value in column A is the same name as the new worksheet.

Source sheet

[image: 1]

Destination Sheet

[image: 2]

Here is the code I used to created the new worksheets and the headers needed.

```
Sub CreateBranchSheets()

Dim BranchField As range
Dim BranchName As range
Dim NewWSheet As Worksheet
Dim WSheet As Worksheet
Dim WSheetFound As Boolean
Dim DataWSheet As Worksheet
Dim cell As range, rngData As range

Set DataWSheet = Worksheets("Loans")
Set BranchField = DataWSheet.range("A2", DataWSheet.range("A2").End(xlDown))


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each BranchName In BranchField

    For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WSheet.Name = BranchName Then
            WSheetFound = True
                    Exit For
        Else
            WSheetFound = False
        End If
    Next WSheet
    
    
    If WSheetFound Then
    
   
        Else '
        
        Set NewWSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count))
        NewWSheet.Name = BranchName
        
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "H"
    range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Account Name"
    range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Amount"
    range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Bill Date"
    range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Comment"
    range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Pay Method"
    range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Post Date"
    range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "D"
    range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Detail Amount"
    range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Detail Comment"
    range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Unit"
    range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Job"
    range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "GLAccount ID"
    range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Property Short Name"
    range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "H"
    range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "21st Mortgage Corporation"
    range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R3C7,Loans!C1:C12,11,0)+VLOOKUP(R3C7,Loans!C1:c12,12,0)"
    range("F3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Enter Invoice Date"
    range("G3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveSheet.Name
    range("H3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ACH"
    range("I3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=today()"
    
   
    
    End If

Next BranchName


For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    WSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

Next WSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered. 
[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). 

Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 0):

you could either use `AutoFilter()` method of `Range` object or the `Dictionary` object

here's an example of the latter

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateBranchSheets()

    Dim loanDict As Object
        Set loanDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        With ThisWorkbook
        
            With .Worksheets("Loans")
                Dim loanCel As Range
                    For Each loanCel In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
                        loanDict(loanCel.Value2) = loanDict(loanCel.Value2) & loanCel.Offset(, 2).Value2 & " "
                    Next
            End With
        
            Dim loan As Variant
                For Each loan In loanDict
                    If Not IsThereSheet(ThisWorkbook, CStr(loan)) Then
                        Dim units As Variant
                            units = Split(Trim$(loanDict(loan)), " ")
                            With .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
                                .Name = loan
                                
                                .Range("D4").Resize(UBound(units) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(units)
                            End With
                    End If
                Next
        
        End With        
End Sub    

Function IsThereSheet(wb As Workbook, sheetName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
    IsThereSheet = Not sh Is Nothing
End Function
```